# Display fb and twitter share page on a lightbox

Tags: twitter, popup, lightbox, share

I need some help, is it possible to display fb or twitter share page on the lightbox instead of new popup window ?

I would like to open the url something like this on the lightbox:

twitter:
https://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20Trinity%20Web%20Tech%20-%20http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FzwYo0C%20via%20@bwg%20http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2Fz6Rc0b

facebook:
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.creativisite.com%2Fbwg%2F2012%2F03%2F05%2Ftrinity-web-tech%2F&t=Trinity%20Web%20Tech

Currently, when its opened on the lightbox, its display white box.
I think it's because twitter or fb doesn't allow to open in an iframe.

Any workaround would be nice ?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [lightbox](http://www.grafikart.fr/zoombox) with this code :

```
<a title="This is an Inception ! zoombox inside a zoombox inside a zoombox" href="http://grafikart.fr/zoombox" class="zoombox">Iframe</a>
```

The final code would give this:

```
<a title="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/share?text=Check%20out%20Trinity%20Web%20Tech%20-%20http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FzwYo0C%20via%20@bwg%20http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2Fz6Rc0b" class="zoombox">Twitter</a>
<a title="Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.creativisite.com%2Fbwg%2F2012%2F03%2F05%2Ftrinity-web-tech%2F&t=Trinity%20Web%20Tech" class="zoombox">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: thx for your answer. but it's still blank. I meant if its use any lightbox it will not work, its no matter if we use any kind of lightbox. but the problem seems on the iframe issue

Comment: I just tried and indeed, it does not work. According to the error that IE returns me, this is related to security.
 Here is a translation of the error (from a message in French) :
"To ensure the security of any information you enter on this website, the publisher of this content does not allow its display in a frame."

Comment: Hmm, I see. so it means it's not possible to display the share page on the lightbox, right ? or do you have any solution to be able display the share page on lightbox ? I think its will be tricky..

Comment: It is to fight against phishing (for example) so I think it's not possible and it's the publisher (Facebook and Twitter in this case) that has this protection.

Comment: thanks for the info. I really appreciate it. I think I'll display it on new pop up window instead.